How to use Quarkus Panache with Postgres JSONB operators
Is there support for PostgreSQL jsonb operators (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) in Quarkus Panache?
I am trying to check for the existence of a JSON value in a jsonb PostgreSQL field in a PanacheRepository / Panache query like:
list("select a from myentity a where a.jsonMappings @> :jsonVal", Parameters.with("jsonVal", val.getAsString()));

However, Panache mis-interprets the '@' symbol.
I tried escaping it in different ways to no avail.
The error I get:

Method threw 'org.hibernate.query.SyntaxException' exception.
At 1:47, token recognition error at: '@'

Similarly for the ? jsonb operator checking for the existence of a key in the JSON field value.

You need to use a native query for that.
MyEntity.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(…)
